# WebBrowser Control download file in session

Tags: c#, .net, webbrowser-control, webclient

I'm using `WebBrowser control` to navigate through a login page and download a file. Since I can't find a way to manage the download automatically with the control I'm using the `WebClient` class to try and achieve this.

Problem is that since the `WebClient` isn't in the same context/session as the browser all i'm downloading is the Security Error screen.

Any ideas on how I can pass the context of the `WebBrowser` session to the `WebClient`?

Comment: A late answer for future references: `URLDownloadToCacheFile` [can be used for this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19025793/1768303).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should be simply a matter of emulating the cookies and headers in the WebBrowser session and re-using them to impersonate the session in WebClient, but it looks like you're already hot on that path.

Here's how I'd proceed.

1. **Get cookies and headers from WebBrowser.**

   Cookies:  You can get the cookies from your WebBrowser session by handling the DocumentCompleted event of the WebBrowser control and parsing the cookie set from DocumentCompleted event.

   Headers:  Use a proxy like Fiddler [www.fiddler2.com/] to read the headers so you'll know what's required by the server.
2. **Utilize identity collected above for WebClient.**

   Headers:  Iterate through all your collected headers and be sure they are [added to the webclient](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.headers.aspx) using `myWebClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");` for example

   Cookies: See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1777221/c-using-cookiecontainer-with-webclient-class).

Comment: I started testing this. It'll take a bit of time but I'll let you know how I go. Thanks

Answer (score 13):

After one week googling a trying for a solution I found one that is so simple!

I you what to silently download a file in an HTTPS URL and a webbrowser control just do this.

1) Log in using the webbrowser
 2) use this code to download.

```
//build de URL 

  string _url = "https://........."

  //define a download file name and location

  string _filename = @"C:\Users\John\Documents\somefile.pdf";

  //create a webcliente

  WebClient cliente = new WebClient();

  //do some magic here (pass the webbrowser cokies to the webclient)

  cliente.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.Cookie, webBrowser1.Document.Cookie);

  //and just download the file

  cliente.DownloadFile(_urlpdf, _filename);
```

It solved my problem

Comment: Thanks! I actually worked. You saved me a lot of time.

Comment: You safed my life with the coockies!!

Comment: The answer what I'm looking for! Thank you very much!