# Skip "Download file" dialog in WebBrowser control

Tags: c#, winforms, download, webbrowser-control

I submit form in WebBrowser control this way:
`WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("INS_TASK").InvokeMember("click");`

where "INS_TASK" is submit button Id. Form submitted with method POST.

If check traffic by Fiddler there are two requests:

1. Result 302, method POST
2. Result 200, method GET

After that "Save file" dialog appears. How to hide this dialog and save downloading file without prompt?

Comment: This has been solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3538874/suppressing-the-save-open-dialog-box-in-a-webbrowser-control/69577989#69577989

Answer (score 0):

Only the user can decide to save files without prompt.
You can't bypass the save file dialog. This is a browser security feature. 
If you could tell the browser to skip the save file dialog then anyone could send malicious .exe files that would be saved directly to disk.

Comment: I think, I can bypass saving dialog. I found samples wich works with WebBrowserNavigatingEventHandler. But in this samples url to file is known ([link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773866/download-file-and-automatically-save-it-to-folder)

Comment: WebBrowser class is found in System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser so I think that's a windows forms application, not a web app. You can use that piece of code but it will download the file on the server, where the application runs, not on the client.

Comment: But what I showld do when I don't have link to file? What url I have to put in client.DownloadDataAsync(Url) ?